# How to Convert .DDF files into tiff in php

Tags: php, converters, imagemagick-convert

In a directory i have thousands of **.ddf** file .

i want batch convert this directory to tiff files. i try this with imagemagick but magick not support this format.

somebody know how to convert this files ?

Comment: What are they? There are multiple applications that uses the extension `.ddf`.

Comment: @Mangnus Eriksson i want write my application that work with ddf format and know there are multiple application that work with .ddf format. what is your comment ?!

Comment: _"and know there are multiple application that work with .ddf format"_ - You need to tell us know what your `.ddf`-files actually _is_. What do they contain? What application do they come from? You can't just convert any file type to `tiff`. For example, if they are meta-data files or PSQL Data Dictionary Files, how would you expect to convert them to `tiff` and what would you expect the result to be?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have old software that scan documents in it with .ddf format  and view them into it . and know i want rewrite this software and view this scanned file into my software but can't show .ddf format !?